# What is the closest font to this font on a booklet about Theo Van Doesburg?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

This is a font I found that I would like to make a project with, however I cannot find one similar. It almost looks like helvetica, but the S, R and B are much different.

**I tried using WhatTheFont and Identifont**

**WhatTheFont** gave me *Eurydome Condensed*, which is very close, but the R,B and E of the sample are all crossed up higher.

**Identifont** gave me *Bryant Compressed*, which isn't very close

Any help is extremely appreciated, Thanks.

[image: Image of font]

This one I used for WhatTheFont:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Venus Halbfett](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/venus/venushalbfett/) seems to be a good candidate.

[image]

Comment: Any hint on how you found it?

Comment: Sure... I first googled to find an image with good quality and flat. Not hard, since it's a record sleeve. Then whattheFont did the job :-)